# Why does my download button activate twice in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinywidgets

So I have a shiny app (https://github.com/tadeu95/BAGs) (http://tadeu-apps.shinyapps.io/bags) and I have several download buttons. Recently what has started to happen is that when I click the download button it activates two times and downloads the same file twice. The thing is that the app worked for almost a year without any problem.
I've tried on chrome, edge and mozzila and happens every time. I don't know what happened because I didn't touch the part of the code where the downloads are implemented.

One thing I've just discovered is that if instead of clicking the download button with the left button of the mouse, I click the  right button and choose "open link in a new tab", it downloads the file correctly only once.

This is a short reproducible app, I advise that you give as input "ursidae" as it downloads the file pretty quickly:

```
library(bold)
library(readr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


grades2<-function(groups){
  taxon9<-bold_seqspec(taxon=groups, format = "tsv")
}


ui <- fluidPage(textInputAddon(inputId="taxa2",addon=icon("search"),width="500px",label=tags$h5(tags$strong("Enter the name of the taxonomic group or groups separated by commas, without spaces:")),placeholder="Example: Carnivora,Ursidae,Artiodactyla,Soricomorpha"),downloadBttn("downloadData_2",size="sm","Download"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  taxaInput_2 <- reactive({grades2(unlist(strsplit(input$taxa2, ",")))})
  output$downloadData_2 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$taxa2,sep_out=",", ".tsv")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      shiny::withProgress(
        message=paste0("Downloading and annotating library for ",input$taxa2,sep_out=","), detail='This may take several minutes',
        value=10,
        {
          shiny::incProgress(10/10)
          write_tsv(taxaInput_2(), file)
        }
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

If anyone has any idea what the reason might be, I will be very thankful.

Comment: Please make a short example app to reproduce the issue with a single button

Comment: yes I'll add it shortly, sorry